# Property don't update

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I beginner in iOs programming. I have some problem. I have MasterViewController, code below

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *str;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.str = @"1234";
}
```

and I send property "str" to DetailViewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSString *object = self.str;
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

after, I change str

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;


    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.detailItem = @"1233";
}
```

after, I come back to MasterViewController but str don't change. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're just changing which object the `detailItem` property refers to in `DetailViewController`, rather than changing the value of the object itself. When you set `self.detailItem` in the `viewDidLoad` method, the `str` property `MasterViewController` will continue to point to the original string:

Before:

```
MasterViewController.str -> 1234 <- DetailViewController.detailItem
```

Then you do `self.detailItem = 1233`. It doesn't change the value of the strings themselves, but just makes detailItem point to a new string. Looking at the graph below, it moves the arrow pointing from DetailViewController rather than changing the content of "1234" itself:

```
MasterViewController.str -> 1234
                            1233 <- DetailViewController.detailItem
```

What you want to do here is use the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) pattern to properly notify the MasterViewController of changes in the detail controller and give it access to the new value.

DetailViewController.h:

```
// declare the delegate protocol
@class DetailViewController;
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)detailViewControllerChangedDetailItem:(DetailViewController *)detailController;
@end

@interface DetailViewController
// add a property for the delegate
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *detailItem;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
        // notify the delegate whenever the detailItem changes
        [self.delegate detailViewControllerChangedDetailItem:self];
   }
}
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
// mark this as implementing the delegate protocol
@interface MasterViewController () <DetailViewControllerDelegate> {
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSString *object = self.str;
        // wire up the delegate connection
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        // now whenever detailItem changes in the DetailViewController,
        // it will notify its delegate (the master VC)
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

// implement the delegate method
-(void)detailViewControllerChangedDetailItem:(DetailViewController *)detailController
{
    // now you can get a copy of the new detailItem value 
    // and do whatever you want with it.
    self.str = detailController.detailItem;
}
```